# Can't set headers (any) on .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

I've tried different approaches just in case there would a bug (found somewhere info that there was missing code for one of those methods).

```
  HttpContext.Response.Headers["2"] = "22";
            Response.Headers["3"] = "3";
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers["4"] = "4";
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["5"] = "5";
            this.Response.Headers["6"] = "6";
            this.Request.Headers["7"] = "7";
            Request.Headers.Add("Test", $"Bearer {2222}");
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Test", "test");
            Response.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {222}");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("Apped", "aa");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Append("fasfasdf", "fsadf");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("3333", "r33r");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("r32f432g34g", "8888");
            this.Response.Headers.Add("1", "a");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd("f", "f");
```

I've tried Return View(), return 200, return redirect to action.

Chrome shows those on Response headers, but won't set them.

I am using local VS 2019, .net core 2.2, newest chrome.

Any idea ??

Comment: "Chrome shows those on Response headers, but won't set them." What does that mean? If you can see them in the response headers tab in Chrome, then they were set. The server has done all it can do. What happens with those headers client-side is a completely different question.

Comment: So I can see those on Response headers, but Chrome/Firefox won't attach them to next request. Unless I've wrongly assumed the headers needs to be set per request/response basis (this is for custom authentication bearer with custom logic)

Comment: The server returns the headers, client side sets the headers for the next request

Comment: Don't know why I've assumed that header would be persistent :/, for some reason I never thought about it.

Basically I need client that will set it, then middleware that will do it every request (if present).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing, Chris Pratt & David Edel are right.

Headers has to be set per each reaquest / response.

Headers are not persistent.

Solution:

1. Send header for response from API/UI
2. Set header for request from a client
3. Add middleware in C# .net core that will check for certain headers & repeat them for the response.